# Event if button is clicked as many times as you write in input

Tags: javascript, html

This simple code is supposed to give an alert when the button is pressed the amount of times you wrote in the input. There is no error or something but the code just doesn't work. Am I stupid and did I miss something or is the logic of my code just wrong? and how do make it work?

```js
var rand1, rand2, text1, text2
let count = 0;

var correct = 0;
function button(){
  text1 = document.getElementById("number").value;
  rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
  rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
  var html = "<br><br><input type='number' id='id'> <button onclick=' check() '> check </button> " + Number(rand2) + '+' + Number(rand1);
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = html;

}
function check(){
  text2 = document.getElementById('questions').value;
  var answer = rand1 + rand2;
  var text11 = document.getElementById('id').value;

  if(answer == text11) {
    var h = "<input type='number' id='id'> " + " <button onclick=' check() '> check </button> " + correct + '/' + text2 + '<br>' + count;
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = h;
    setTimeout(wait, 3000);
    document.getElementById("but").disabled = true;
    correct = correct + 1;
    count = count + 1;
  } else {
    count = count + 1;
    var b = "<input type='number' id='id'> " + " <button onclick=' check() '> check </button> "  + correct + '/' + text2 + '<br>' + count;
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = b;
    setTimeout(wait, 3000);
    document.getElementById("but").disabled = true;
}
if (count === text2){
  alert(correct + '/' + text2);
}
function wait(){
  button()
}
  }
```

```html
<p>maximum number:<input type="text" id="number"></p>
<p>how many questions?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
<button onclick="button()" id = 'but'> ok </button>
<div id = 'div'> </div>
```

Comment: @red_panda you have to read the value of the input inside `check()`

Comment: What's `correct `? Also, you need to move `text1 = document.getElementById('questions').value;` inside your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.value` returns a string and you must convert it into a number (if you want to) before using it.

So in line 6 do this:

```
text1 = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
```

and also in the `check()` function:

```
text2 = Number(document.getElementById('questions').value);
```

Hope that works.